# Read Data in Firebase with VueJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I'm trying to read data from my firebase database. The structure looks as follows:

```
names
  |---- forms
         |---- step1
                 |---- -KxrySGBHgLvw_lPPdRA
                                |---- name : CantFindMe
```

I manage to read the object: 
{ "-KxrySGBHgLvw_lPPdRA": { "edit": false, "name": "CantFindMe" } }

Using the VueJS binding with:

```
{{personName.forms.step1}}
```

But when I try to add ".name" after ".step1", that should supposedly return "CantFindMe", I get nothing/blank back.

How do I get to the name property using VueJs to return "CantFindMe"?

Comment: It would need to be `{{ personName.forms.step1["-KxrySGBHgLvw_lPPdRA"].name }}`

Comment: @thanksd Its very naive advice :D

Comment: Show me more code. I need to know how you are referencing / querying data from Fbase.

Comment: @WaldemarIce not advising he put that in his code, just saying where the "CantFindMe" value is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve Firebase data in Vuejs with Vuefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064624/retrieve-firebase-data-in-vuejs-with-vuefire)

Comment: Yes...i will be deleting this question!

Answer (score 1):

Possible quick fix. Change:

```
{{personName.forms.step1}}
```

to:

```
{{personName.forms.step1.val().name}}
```

Or edit your question and add more code, especially where you are referencing / querying data from Firebase.

Comment: Added a new question with full code here gentlemen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064624/retrieve-firebase-data-in-vuejs-with-vuefire